# Scalatest Scalamock behaves differently with same function declared two ways

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalamock

If I have a Scala trait with two functions defined on it, one defined using just the signature `def foo : Int => String` and the other function declared with a paramter and a return type `def bar(myInt : Int): String` then I get different behavior for those methods.

```
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class DefTest {

  trait DefTrait {
    def foo : Int => String
    def bar(myInt: Int) : String
  }

  class DefTest extends WordSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {
    val defStub = stub[DefTrait]

    defStub.bar _ when * returns "Works"
    defStub.foo _ when * return "nope"

  }
}
```

[image: Signature only fail]

IntellJ says there are `Too many arguments for method when` and `expected: FunctionAdapter0[Boolean], actual: MatchAny`.

SBT says:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.scalamock.matchers.MatchAny
[error]  required: org.scalamock.function.FunctionAdapter0[Boolean]
[error]     defStub.foo _ when * returns "nope"
[error]                        ^
```

This makes me wonder:

1. What is the difference between these two types of function declarations? I thought they were equivalent and I seem to have been able to use them interchangeably up until now.
2. Is it possible to use the signature function definition `foo: Int => String` with the `defStub.foo _ when 42 return "yay"` syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. What is the difference between these two types of function declarations?**

For `def foo : Int => String` it's returning a **high-order** function without accept parameters:

```
scala> :kind -v foo
scala.Function1's kind is F[-A1,+A2]
* -(-)-> * -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.
```

and when you call `foo(2)`, it's equal to `foo.apply(2)`, `apply` method is used for **function** execution.

For `def bar(myInt: Int) : String`, it's a method, that accept a `Int` parameter.

2.**Is it possible to use the signature function definition foo: Int => String with the defStub.foo _ when 42 return "yay" syntax?**

for `def foo : Int => String` it's not accepting parameter, so you should use `when()` for this, and it's returning type is `Int => String`, so you should `returns` a **high order function** for this method. like:

```
defStub.foo _ when() returns((i: Int) => "nope")
```